# Get the name of a named range object without getting the array of named ranges - googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

```
ss.getRangeByName('name').
```

returns a Range.  But shouldn't it return a NamedRange object since it obviously is named?  This leads to the problem of having to now call getNamedRanges() which returns all NamedRange objects in an array which I'd like to avoid if possible.

[spreadsheet_class_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmMu.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is working as intended. As stated in the document:

[getRangeByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getrangebynamename)

> - Returns a named range, or null if no range with the given name is found. If multiple sheets of the spreadsheet use the same range name, specify the sheet name without additional quotation marks — for example, **`getRangeByName('TaxRates') or getRangeByName('Sheet Name!TaxRates'), but not getRangeByName('"Sheet Name"!TaxRates')`**.

In this code, instead of listing all the named range and accessing the range. We use  `getRangeByName(name)` to access the range directly as it return [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html).

```
 // Log the number of columns for the range named 'TaxRates' in the active spreadsheet.
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('TaxRates');
 if (range != null) {
   Logger.log(range.getNumColumns());
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation and I guess my point is this: if I decide to put that return value of getRangeByName into say, the variable 'range' -- I'm unable to later check the name of the range (even though I know it has one!).  I suppose it's because the Range object cannot be counted on to have a name, only a NamedRange would have that.  I get this, however, it's annoying in that it could just return 'null' or something to avoid this problem.  Do you get where I'm coming from?